# I got blocked when I used scrapy and not when I used selenium and request 403 error code

Tags: selenium, python-requests, scrapy, http-status-code-403

I am trying to scrape this website using scrapy
https://www.dnb.com/business-directory/company-profiles.pfizer_inc.140f48fa0b37556f925afcaec7b5c566.html

I tried

1-crawling using scrapy shell

2-rotating user agent and proxies

3-enable COOKIES

4-disable Javascript from the browser to try what happens

this my settings

```
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.25,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 10,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 10,
    'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 100,
    'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 100,
    'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': True,
    # proxy setting
    'RETRY_TIMES': 10,
    'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 408],
    'PROXY_MODE': 0,
    'PROXY_LIST': r'https_proxies_ip.txt',
    'RANDOM_UA_FILE': r'default_uas.txt',
    'RANDOM_UA_PER_PROXY': True,  # for only proxy

    'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES':
        {
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
            'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,

            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
            'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
        }
```

but when I tried selenium and requests without user agents and proxies it worked fine!
my questions are what should I do? and why did this happen?

thanks

Comment: This article may help you : https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/?sfw=pass1628511504

Comment: Add request headers

Comment: thanks but it is not like my problem

Comment: @SuperUserok I will try

Comment: I have tried but it not works also